# Instead of repeating a loop multiple times 'merge' into one

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

**Set-up**

I'm scraping apartment ads using Scrapy. For certain housing characteristics, I loop over the elements of a list `BC` I obtain per ad. If the characteristic is in the list I assign a 'yes' and if not a 'no'. E.g.

```
for x in BC:                
     if 'Terraza' in x:
          terrace = 'yes'
          break
     else:
          terrace = 'no'
```

For each 'yes-no' characteristic I have a copy of the above loop.

---

**Problem**

Besides looping over the elements of the list, I'd like to loop over the characteristics themselves. I.e. I'd like to 'merge' all the loops per characteristic into one loop.

I've tried the following (my actual `bcl` does contain multiple elements):

```
found = False
bcl = ['Terraza']

for x in l: # l is a list of strings containing housing characteristics   
    for y in bcl:               
        if y in x:
           y = 'yes'
           found = True
           break
        else:
           y = 'no'    
    if found:
        break

terrace = Terrazza
```

but this loop does not create the variable `Terrazza`. I'm not sure I can solve this with globals.

How do I make this loop work?

Comment: Is BC a list of stings, a list of lists, or a different data structure?

Comment: list of strings.

Comment: What about `l`? Is it also a list? Can you please provide a sample content of that variable?

Comment: Hi Victor. I've added it to the question.

Comment: I used 'l = ['Terraza', 'Terraa', 'Trraza']' and I have printed y instead of your line'terrace=Terrazza'. It printed 'yes' and came out of the loop after finding it which is expected. I dont think there is any problem with your code according to your question.

Sidenote: if L is a list of strings, and BCL is also a list of strings, you should be ideally be doing 'if y==x' instead of 'if y in x' to avoid unexpected results.

Comment: Please stop writing tags in question titles.

Comment: Please let us know if any of the answers did help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the wanted result, you may take a different approach. In a case like this, I tend to use a more functional style of coding. I am not sure if this is what you intend, but I think you could do it this way:

```
list_characteristics = ['Terraza', "Swimming pool"] # sample ad text - list of strings
bcl = ["test1", "test2", "Terraza", "test3"]  # sample checklist - list of strings 

def check_characteristics(checklist, adlist):    
    list_of_found_items = []
    for characteristic in list_characteristics:
        print("characteristic:", characteristic)
        for item in bcl:
            print("item:", item)
            if item in characteristic:
                list_of_found_items.append(item)
    return list_of_found_items

result_list = check_characteristics(bcl, list_characteristics)
print("This ad has the following characteristics:", result_list)
```

Using the code above, you have a function that takes two lists of strings and lists all the items found. In case you one want to know if there is at least one of those, you can use this other function as a faster, short-circuit, way:

```
list_characteristics = ['Terraza', "Swimming pool"] # ad text - list of strings
bcl = ["test1", "test2", "Terraza", "test3"]  # checklist - list of strings 

def has_any_characteristic(checklist, adlist):    
    for characteristic in list_characteristics:
        for item in bcl:
            if item in characteristic:
                return True
    return False

result = has_any_characteristic(bcl, list_characteristics)
print("This ad has at least one of the wanted characteristics?", result)
```

Seems like a lot of code, but you code it once and then you use it whenever you need it, in a clean and easy to read way, IMHO. The definition of these two functions can even be placed in a separate module that you import where needed. So, in the main code, you will only need to use one line to call the function. Each function allows to answer a simple question in a way that is easy to understand, as presented in the `print()`statements in both code samples above.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't in merging loops but probably in breaking from outer loop. You can break out of a top loop by raising custom exception and then trying to catch it. Take a look at this peace of code:

```
bcl = ['Terraza']


class FoundCharacteristicException(Exception):
    pass


for x in li:
    try:
        for y in bcl:
            if y in x:
                raise FoundCharacteristicException
    except FoundCharacteristicException:
        break
```